# using cropper js with asp.net mvc not getting selected photo name in text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cropperjs, cropper

I am using `cropper js` with my asp.net mvc project to crop and upload image. But I am not getting the name of the selected image in the textbox.

Please see the uploaded images. The first image is a default image, and the second image is the selected image to upload. Although the selected image is shown in the img tag I am not getting the name of the image in the text box. I referred to the example from this page https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/examples/upload-cropped-image-to-server.html

```
@*======= for image upload ================*@
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_image" class="control-label col-md-2">Image</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <img class="rounded" id="avatar" src="~/Files/3456749.jfif" alt="avatar">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="input" name="image" accept="image/*" >
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">0%</div>
    </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Crop the image</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="img-container">
                        <img id="image" src="~/Files/3456749.jfif">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="crop">Crop</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @*===========================================*@
```

Below is my cropper js file, I have removed the server upload section from this file.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var $progress = $('.progress');
    var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
    var $alert = $('.alert');
    var $modal = $('#modal');
    var cropper;

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        var done = function (url) {
            input.value = '';
            image.src = url;
            $alert.hide();
            $modal.modal('show');
        };
        var reader;
        var file;
        var url;

        if (files && files.length > 0) {
            file = files[0];

            if (URL) {
                done(URL.createObjectURL(file));
            } else if (FileReader) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    done(reader.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    });

    $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 1,
            viewMode: 3,
        });
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
    });
    
    document.getElementById('crop').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var initialAvatarURL;
        var canvas;

        $modal.modal('hide');

        if (cropper) {
            canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                width: 160,
                height: 160,
            });
            initialAvatarURL = avatar.src;
            avatar.src = canvas.toDataURL();
            $progress.show();
            $alert.removeClass('alert-success alert-warning');
            canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append('avatar', blob, 'avatar.jpg');

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Cropper js code link
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/js/cropper.js

The first image is default image before selecting any image by the user.
[image]

the second image is when user selects an image from his machine, the image is showing but the name is not showing in the text box.
[image]